# how to configure mysql in orbeon form builder tool

Tags: mysql, datasource, orbeon

I am not a java developer, I tried to install orbeon form builder tool (community edition) in my machine. I configured datasource as per their documentation for "mysql". But when creating a form data it is still using "exist" database. Please help.

Comment: You'll have to tell us more about the exact changes you did. Did you uncompress the `orbeon.war` to Tomcat's `webapps` directory? Did you place a `properties-local.xml` file in `WEB-INF/resources/config`? What is the content of that file?

Comment: I have that file in the same location that you mentioned. But I donot know what to configure in that file.Right now the content of the file is <properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

</properties>

Comment: So you have no properties defined there? Inside the `<properties>` element you [should have](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db.html#with-a-single-schema) `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="mysql"/>`. Does adding this help?